# java static list causes memory leak

Tags: java, arraylist, static, jvm, garbage-collection

I have following code which seems to be causing some memory leaks. This code snippet(i.e. hasPermissions()) get executed every time when a user performs an action.

So from what I understood, since Map ***permissions*** is a static object, all ***permissionsList***  objects that are created inside ***hasPermission()*** method have references to global static object(i.e. ***permissions***); therefore, is not eligible to be garbage collected?

Following is the Leak Suspect showing for its heap dump in Eclipse Memory Analyzer tool. When I navigate to details, it shows the class with following code snippet. I found Java ***List.addAll()*** function internally creates ***LinkedList***. I'm still trying to comprehend what's exactly happening here. Appreciate your thoughts.

[image]

```
public class AccessManager {
    
    
        private static Map <Integer, List> permissions;
    
        public static void init()
        {
            //initiate permissions and add values
        }
        
        public static boolean hasPermissions(List<Integer> accessLevels, String action)
        {
    
            if (permissions == null)
                init();
            
            List permissionsList = null;
            
            for (Integer a : accessLevels) {
                
                if (permissionsList == null) {
                    permissionsList = permissions.get(a);
                } else {
                    permissionsList.addAll(permissions.get(a));
                }
            }
            
            if(permissionsList.contains(action)){
                return true;
            }
            
            return false;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Why are you writing `List` instead of `List<Integer>`? The List `addAll` method only adds to the existing list. It will only be a `LinkedList` if you started with one. Can you explain what these permissions are for and why you're keeping them in a `static` variable?

Comment: The lists will definitely not have a reference to the map that holds them. But the *map* has references to the *lists* which it holds. You don't show how any of the data gets into the map in the first place, nor do you tell us anything about what the expected lifespan is of this data or what, if anything, would ever clear it out. Assuming you just add more and more to it, of course it keeps growing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm going to change the code to below, so that it won't create local object: permissionList inside hasPermission(). Wondering if it would fix the issue.

```
public class AccessManager {


    private static Map <Integer, List> permissions;

    public static void init()
    {
        //initiate permissions and add values
    }
    
    public static boolean hasPermissions(List<Integer> accessLevels, String action)
    {

        if (permissions == null)
            init();
            
        for (Integer a : accessLevels) {
            
            if (permissions.get(a).contains(action)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: preferably you'd only post this as an answer once you've confirmed that it solves the problem

Comment: This code snippet worked as it no longer invokes addAll() which previously added items to static list over and over again.

Comment: `permissions.get(a).contains(action)` will throw a `NullPointerException` when the key is not in the map. You might use `permissions.getOrDefault(a, List.of()).contains(action)` instead. Or `Collections.emptyList()` instead of `List.of()` if you’re using an older Java version.

Answer (score 8):

That code is quite severely broken. In adding new permissions to a `List` referenced by `permissions`, the `hasPermission` method not only creates a memory leak, but may cause subsequent access checks to be incorrectly granted, which might be a quite serious security vulnerability.

For instance, if `permissions` contains

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [a] |
| 2 | [b] |

and you execute `hasPermissions(Arrays.asList(1,2), "b")`, `permissions` will be updated to contain

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [a, b] |
| 2 | [b] |

causing a subsequent call to `hasPermissions(Arrays.asList(1), "b")` to return true.

Also each further call to `hasPermissions(Arrays.asList(1,2), "b")` causes b to be added again:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [a, b, b] |
| 2 | [b] |

causing that list to get longer and longer until memory is exhausted. This extremely long list full of duplicates will slow down access checks such as `hasPermissions(Arrays.asList(1), "c")` to a crawl.

Oh, and by the way, the lazy initialization that calls `init` on first invocation of `hasPermissions` is not thread safe, but potentially accessed by multiple threads. You should either declare permissions `volatile` (or even synchronize `init` if `init` is not safe for use by multiple threads), or invoke `init` in a static initializer.